# Populate DataGridview upon ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a `DataGridView` that is populated on the load of the form.  I have a `ComboBox` filled too on the load of the form.  What I need is when I change the value of the `ComboxBox` the `DataGridView` is populated again but depending on the value I selected on the `ComboBox`.

Right now it is giving me an error that

> *the conection is already open*.

This is the code I have right now.(I´m using windows forms).

Any Ideas on what I´m doing wrong?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    poputateCombo();
    populateDatagridView(s);
}

private void populateDatagridView(string s)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT "values" FROM "table" WHERE seccao = '" + s + "'  ";
        conexao.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conexao);
        DataTable dt1;  dt1 = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt1);
        BindingSource  bsource = new BindingSource();
        bsource.DataSource = dt1;
        dgPlus.DataSource = bsource;
        sda.Update(dt1);
        conexao.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error:" + er.ToString());
    }
}

private void cbSeccoes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    povoaPlus(cbSeccoes.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not open the connection when its already in open state. So check if connection state is not open then only call the `conexao.Open();`

```
if(!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
    conexao.Open()
```

Second thing, your code syntax is not looking correct.

```
string query = "SELECT "values" FROM "table" WHERE seccao = '" + s + "'  ";
```

Above line will not even compile.

You may want write this

```
string query = "SELECT values FROM table WHERE seccao = '" + s + "'  ";
```

Or if you are trying to send the column name and Table name with the help of variable then it would be

```
string query = "SELECT " + values +" FROM " + table +" WHERE seccao = '" + s + "'  ";
```

Even this will compile but I would not suggest you to use this. Instead of this use parameterized query to avoid the *SqlInjection*

In your combobox's `SelectedIndexChanged` even call the method which binds the datagridview.

```
private void cbSeccoes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I'm not sure what does this method work
    //povoaPlus(cbSeccoes.Text);

    // I think you should call this    
    populateDatagridView(string s)
}
```

Comment: I just wrote "values" and "table" instead of the real data.....  Sorry if i confused you.. I i´ll try your solution,  thanks for the reply     UPDATE: Worked..silly me..not checking the connetion ..